# How to check if map has a key using lens syntax?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

How to check if map has a key using lens syntax?

```
import qualified Map as Map

let x = Map.member "bla" m
```

How to write this using lenses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`has`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.4/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v%3ahas).

```
M.fromList [("bla", ())] & has (ix "bla")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use the `Contains` instance.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.4/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#t%3aContains)

```
>>> Map.fromList [("bla", ())] ^. contains "bla"
True

>>> Map.fromList [("bla", ())] & contains "bla" .~ False
Map.fromList []
```

Comment: I tried, but looks like instance of Map for Contains was removed from the latest lens 4.0.4

Comment: Oh, I'm using an old version.